# Sour/musty tasting mead

Tags: techniques, mead, sour, help

My son and I tried our hand at mead for the first time... I didn't notice a lot of bubbling I thought that it wasn't fermenting correctly but my son thought differently, he's 17. Lol

But when we went to bottle it after the normal 2-week. We tasted it and it tasted sour kind of musty It wasn't a good flavor.

Does anybody possibly know what we could have done wrong?

Thank you.

On a side note he decided to try to make ginger beer and I felt that the ginger beer had a similar taste to it not as strong as the mead but still it was there.

Could it be the tub that we're using?

Thanks ahead for the help

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there might be some yeast still floating around in it. Try sealing it for a while and letting it age. This has always helped mellow out the flavor and then rack out the yeast.

Answer (score 0):

Thatguy is probably right- none of my meads, which use less honey, quick-fermenting beer yeasts, and nutrients to speed things up, have ever been ready in less than a month. You can try to rapidly settle out yeast by putting it in a fridge or a freezer.

All of the above is assuming you are taking gravity readings. Without checking, you won't know if the yeast even started fermenting anything. A batch isn't considered done until there has been no change in gravity for about a week- and sometimes it stalls for even longer than that- and there is no guarantee of visual activity even if it's still going.